# My MATLAB algorithm which finds sum of "n" amount of fibonacci numbers is not working and i don't know why

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sum, fibonacci

I were creating algorithms to practice MATLAB syntax. I wanted to create a function that finds the sum of "n" amount of fibonacci numbers. So i created this.

```
function fibtoplam(n):
fib_seri = [1 1];
fib_toplam = 0;
for i = 1:n;
    fib_seri = [fib_seri (fib_seri(length(fib_seri))+(fib_seri(length(fib_seri)-1)];
end
for y = 1:length(fib_seri);
    fib_toplam = fib_toplam + fib_seri(y);
end
end

fibtoplam(5);
```

So i get an error message which tells me there is a undefined variable but i could not recognize the error. Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Diagnosing "an error" is **much** easier for us if you actually provide the full error!! [Edit] your question, and format the error by adding a `>` at the start of the line, to put it in a block quote.

Comment: MATLAB will not just say "undefined variable". It will tell you the name of the variable that is not defined, and it will tell you what line of the code it is at. Please include all of that information in your question. Additionally, please read [this part of the MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html), which will tell you about how to define and call a function in a script. I think this is where you problem lies.

Comment: "Algoritma 1
Undefined function or variable 'Algoritma'."  I get this message from command window (Algoritma 1 is file name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab requires that function names are without spaces as it interprets spaces as being the end of function names.

```
clear all % calls the function "clear" with the argument 'all'
algoritma 1 % tries to call the function algoritma with the argument '1'
```